# Can I fill a range using a __restrict declared pointer?

Tags: visual-c++

Can I do the following:

```
int * __restrict arr = new int [100];
std::fill_n(arr + 50, 50, 1); // the arr + 50 temporary aliases arr??
std::fill_n(&arr[50],50,1); // is this ok? No aliasing?
```

This probably applies to the C standard and to just about every c++ compiler, but I'm only familiar with visual C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict:

> It says that for the lifetime of the pointer, only it or a value
>   directly derived from it (such as pointer + 1) will be used to access
>   the object to which it points.

`arr + 50` is ok, as it is derived from `arr`, which is a `restrict`ed pointer.

Comment: You're a very gifted user of the internet, thank you.